# Local Machine Registry Key values not matching when trying to fetch from C#

Tags: c#, windows-services, registry

I am trying to get list of all Installed application from Registry but the Key Values from Registry at
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` are not matching with the values my code is fetching.

#### Code snippet for fetching Keys from Local Machine_32 - similar for CurrentUser and Local Machine 64

```
key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall", false);
foreach (String keyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
{
    RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(keyName);
    displayName = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") != null ? subkey.GetValue("DisplayName").ToString() : "";
    version = subkey.GetValue("DisplayVersion") != null ? subkey.GetValue("DisplayVersion").ToString() : "";
    install_date = subkey.GetValue("InstallDate") != null ? subkey.GetValue("InstallDate").ToString() : "";
    publisher = subkey.GetValue("Publisher") != null ? subkey.GetValue("Publisher").ToString() : "";
    install_location = subkey.GetValue("InstallSource") != null ? subkey.GetValue("InstallSource").ToString() : "";
    if (displayName != "")
    {
        installedAppsB.Add(new SoftwareInventory()
            {
                key = keyName,
                app_name = displayName,
                version = version,
                install_date = install_date,
                publisher = publisher,
                install_location = install_location,
                reg_source = "LM-SOFTWARE-Microsoft-Windows-CurrentVersion-Uninstall"
        });
    }
}
```

For Example I am not seeing `Node.js` in my records but it is there in My Registry.

#### Registry

[image]

#### Data from my Code

[image]

I tried elevating permissions using the following value in `app.manifest`:
`<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`
but still no help.

I Also tried matching the list of all Installed Applications found by [NirSoft UnintallView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/uninstall_view.html) which is finding `108 Apps` vs my code finding `186 Apps` looking in all `CurrentUser`, `LocalMachine_32` & `LocalMachine_64` registry.

What am I doing wrong here. Please advice, Thanks

Comment: please show the relevant code.

Comment: Hey @JHBonarius just edited my question, Thanks

Comment: Did you look if the RegKey GUID is in the list? Maybe there are leading whitespaces or other characters?

Comment: Is it perhaps getting redirected to "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I believe so cause none of the Keys are matching, just found out through manual matching.

Comment: @JHBonarius Initially I thought so but then I tried explicitly look for only `Node.js` in the Key but it was not getting that.

Comment: @MatthewWatson logging the Key shows this value `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` I am totally confused what is happening here

Comment: `WOW6432Node` redirection means the key name will stay the same. Are you **sure** you are running in 64-bit, what is the value of `IntPtr.Size`?

Comment: @Charlieface @Mathew Watson @JHBonarius So my Debug was set to `Any CPU` and when I changed it to `x64` I was able to get all the values from desired Registry Key. But still should `Any CPU` means literally any ?

Comment: Yup that's what it means: whatever I (the computer) feel like doing today

Comment: Lol, Gotchya, Thanks folks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Debug option on my Visual Studio was set to `Any CPU` when I changed to config to `x64` my code was able to fetch values from correct Registry Key i.e `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` and didn't get redirected to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` as @Charlieface and @MatthewWatson have mentioned in the comment.